# Rumor of New Edition of Friedman Shulchan Aruch

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch

I heard that a smaller and more user-friendly edition of Mechon Yerushalaim's Friedman Shulchan Aruch is going to be released. Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: Is there some way to contact them? They are more likely to know than us

Comment: I emailed them, but haven't heard back. I was just curious if one of you might known

Comment: is this on topic

Comment: @ezra feels to me that yes. It is a product recommendation question on a very important halachic text